# PHP - Convert file data into an array based on common strings in the file

Tags: php

I have a file that has several lines of data.  I would like every 33 lines of data to be grouped into an array, after that data is grouped into an array I'd like to colon delimitate the data into sub arrays like so:

```
<?
 print_r(explode(':', $line));
?>
```

How do I prep the every 33 lines of data in the file to get ready to become my $line variable in the snippet above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will fit your goal, but take a look at `array_chunk`.  For your scenario, assuming your data is coming from a file (if not, you can explode to split lines into an array):

```
 $line_array = file($location_of_data_file);

 $line_array_by_33 = array_chunk($line_array, 33);
```

This wil give you an array like:

```
[0] =>
      [0] => "Line 1",
      [1] => "Line 2",
      [2] => "Line 3",
      [3] => "Line 4",
[1] =>
      [0] => "Line 5",
      [1] => "Line 6",
      [2] => "Line 7",
      [3] => "Line 8",
```

The above is a shorter version, but you get the idea.

If you need to add your delimiter, you can always implode each chunk, add your token, and then re-explode.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the Delay!

Answer (score 0):

Based on an [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/), try something like:

```
$counter = 1;
$group_of_lines = '';
$file_handle = fopen("myfile", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    $group_of_lines .= $line;

    if($counter % 33 == 0) {
        // do stuff with your $group_of_lines
    }

    $counter++;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Thank you this will help in the future!